# How to apply the Dirichlet conditions to Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

When checking whether a function is equal to its Fourier series one can use the Dirichlet conditions.

If they are satisfied, one gets that $f$ is equal to its Fourier series wherever it is continuous. At the points of dicontinuity the Fourier series converges to the mean of the left and right limit of $f$ at that point.

So far, so good!

Except:

Usually, in problems involving Fourier series, the function could be something like $x^2$ **but restricted** to $[0,2\pi]$ and then periodically continued on all of $\mathbb R$.

In which case, if I'm not mistaken, there are points of discontinuity at $2\pi k$ so the Fourier series would only represent the function on points not equal to $2 \pi k$. (maybe unless by coincidence, the two limits are equal so that the mean value of them is equal to each limit? but then the function would still have a spike and not be continuous there)

Am I missing something? I'm asking because I just read through an example with $f(x) = x^4 - \pi x^2$ on $[-\pi,\pi)$ and this $f$ is supposedly continuous on all of $\mathbb R$. Is this a typo?

Comment: This is an even function and its even periodic extension is continuous (though not differentiable every $2\pi k$

Comment: Spiky points doesn't mean discontinuity. It can be perfectly continuous. What I always suggest is to graph three functions one below the other: $f(x)$ given, its periodic extension, and $S(x)$ the sum of the resulting Fourier Series. That should clear up a bit your continuity doubts.

Comment: @Luciano Thank you! Then my mistake was to think that the spikes are points of discontinuity. I did draw $f$ and its periodic extension but not the Fourier series because I am unsure how to do it without suitable computer software (which I don't have, unfortunately).

Comment: Free Geogebra software from www.geogebra.org will let you construct Fourier Series. I can email you a short doc walking you through it if you like.